# How do I fit a function for a plot like this

Tags: regression, linear-model, nonlinear-regression, exploratory-data-analysis

The blue dot is the (0,0) point.

So there is clearly a reverse relationship between X and Y. but its not exactly linear. the slope is also deeper on the positive side of X.

What kind of mathematical function can I use to transform the plot to fit a linear regression?

I prefer a transformation to a linear relationship, but I am open to some fancy non-linear model.

[image]

Comment: The point of finding a function is to understand the nature of the system you are observing. Unless you are sure that the deviations (from linear) are a result of errors or some other factor, you shouldn't try to force-fit a linear function to this plot.

Comment: Although I sympathize with the philosophy in the opening of the comment by @Sas3, I have to (strongly) disagree with the suggestion that one should not attempt to linearize an observed relationship.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35711 for an effective approach to this problem.  Read John Tukey's book *EDA* for a full account.