# What types of transformation besides logarithm can I use for a linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, feature-engineering, logarithm

I'm used to use log transformation in linear regression, most of times so I can get a normally distributed variable (even though I know this is not a requirement). I was wondering, what other transformations can I apply both to my independent and dependent variable and what gains in using them?

Comment: why do you think that taking log transform gives you normally distributed features?

Comment: @gunes as far as I know, taking the log can reduce the variability and this makes your data closer to a normal distribution, which then helps for some algorithm. There are several courses which shows this. If that's a problem, this is also something I might appreciate some insights

Comment: Please [search our site for "Box Cox"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=box+cox).  For additional ideas, look at the posts tagged with [tag:data-transformation].  The better answers demonstrate why the "several courses which show this" are not generally correct.  I illustrate a principled approach to transforming regression variables at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/35717/919.

Comment: @whuber I totally agree that "several courses show" is not an argument. This is just from where I took the idea and, as I said, I really appreciate some insights on that. I will take a look at the links you sent. Many thanks.

Comment: check this blog might give you some inspirations https://towardsdatascience.com/types-of-transformations-for-better-normal-distribution-61c22668d3b9